# modifying an existing menu to have submenus using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I current have the following menu structure defined within a masterpage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SubNavigation" runat="server">
    <ul>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 1", "/item1/", null, null) %></li>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 2", "/item2/blah/", null, "nofollow")%></li>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 3", "/item3/blah/", null, "nofollow") %></li>
    </ul>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

As people navigate around the site the RenderLink method get called and checks to see if the user is current on the requested page and renders it as  tag with specific css.

Now I'm wanting to add a submenu like so:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SubNavigation" runat="server">
    <ul>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 1", "/item1/", null, null) %></li>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 2", "/item2/blah/", null, "nofollow")%></li>
    <li><%= RenderLink("item 3", "/item3/blah/", null, "nofollow") %></li>
        <li class="topitem">
            <%= RenderLink("Item 4", "/Item4/blah/", null, null) %>
            <ul class="sublist">
                <li class="subitem">
                    <%= RenderLink("subitem4a", "/subitem4a/blah/", null, null) %></li>
                <li class="subitem">
                    <%= RenderLink("subitem4b", "/subitem4b/blah/", null, null) %></li>
                <li class="subitem">
                    <%= RenderLink("subitem4c", "/subitem4c/blah/", null, null) %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to use jquery so that when a user clicks on an Item that has the class topitem the user is derected to the corresponding URL and the submenu is then displayed, once a user moves off a page that isn't the topitem or any subitems the submenu is closed.

I have been trying the following jquery but haven't had any joy...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.topitem > a:first-child').siblings().toggle();
});
```

obviously this has a knock-on effect of showing/hiding any li.topitems and its siblings which is not good if there is another submenu defined within my menu structure.

What is the best way to handle this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be accomplished solely in jQuery or if that's even the right move here.  The way you are binding the jquery functions looks fine to me.

If you want a submenu to appear on a certain page, you should be running the list elements through some type of loop that checks to see if you are on the right page.  The code you posted here is basically just HTML markup.

I don't know ASP but in PHP this is pretty straightforward with an if/else loop.  In the if loop, you could make the condition a variable passed through the URL that ASP grabs.